# Why do I get a "Post" 404 error when submitting an ajax contact form in WP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form

I'm in the process of building an ajax contact-form for a WordPress theme and am running into an issue when submitting the form; the console keeps saying it can't retrieve my mail-form.php file (used to format the email) when I'm pretty sure I've got the url right.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mail-form.php",
    cache: false,
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
    success: function (html) {
        jQuery("#contact-form").slideUp("slow");
        jQuery("#contact-form").after("<p><span class='center' id='send-message'>Your message has been sent! We will reply shortly!</span></p>");
        jQuery("#send-message").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Here is  a link to the form... http://wordpress-dev.designer17.com/contact/

The last time I used this it worked just fine, so I'm quite bewildered by this.

Comment: Pretty sure you've got the URL right? Double and triple check it until you're absolutely sure.

Comment: you at the generated page source and see what the `url:` looks like client-side, then try to hit that url yourself via the browser's address bar. You could also check the server's error log to see what was requested when the 404 occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using PHP within your .js file (line 56):

```
url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mail-form.php",
```

What you can do is add this to your main template:

```
var TEMPLATE_URI = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>";
```

then within your .js file use:

```
url: TEMPLATE_URI + "/mail-form.php",
```

Comment: What are you meaning by "main template?"

Comment: @Designer17, put it in your footer.php

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript, $.ajax function call in this case, is client side and is not parsed by php, which is server side. Because of this the JavaScript parser interprets the string "" as a literal string and it is not parsed. To solve this simple use a relative url or generate the JavaScript in a php template which can parse the php code.

Remember: Code is always parsed/rendered serverside, sent back to the client's browser, then client side scripting, JavaScript code in your case, executes in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I supose you moved your javascript onto a .js file, however unless you instruct your http server to process javascript files as php any php inside them is just text.

Either move the function back into a php file or (better approach) pass the URL as an attribute, for example:

```
// PHP FILE
<form action="URLGOESHERE" id="form_id">
  ...

// JAVASCRIPT FILE
var url = $("#form_id").attr("action");
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    ...
```